# How to ingest a .json file from persistent volume to elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I have a web crawler that crawls thousands of websites and store that in a persistent volume on Kubernetes.

After that pod is terminated, I want to ingest the .json file inside the PV into ECK. I have achieved running elastic search and Kibana successfully. Also, I'm following the [Quickstart](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat will do this for you - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.14/decode-json-fields.html

ps - it's Elasticsearch, not elasticsearch ;)

Comment: Sorry about the Elasticsearch thing ;p
I checked both links you posted @Mark but neither one of them shows you how to read a .json file but how to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filebeat without autodiscover like documented at [filbeat-no-autodiscover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-beat-configuration-examples.html#k8s_filebeat_without_autodiscover) as a base config.

Then you can mount your PV to the filebeat filesystem via a volume and a volume mount.

Finally you can use the filestream.input to read the file from disk and stream it to ECK and add a ndjson parser to parse the json from text.

Something like the following

```
apiVersion: beat.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Beat
metadata:
  name: filebeat
spec:
  type: filebeat
  version: 8.4.2
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch
  kibanaRef:
    name: kibana
  config:
    filebeat.inputs:
    - type: filestream
      id: my-filestream-id
      paths:
        - /my/pv/path
      parsers:
        - ndjson:
            target: ""
            message_key: msg
    processors:
    - add_host_metadata: {}
    - add_cloud_metadata: {}
  daemonSet:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        automountServiceAccountToken: true
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
        hostNetwork: true # Allows to provide richer host metadata
        containers:
        - name: filebeat
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
            #privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
          - name: varlogcontainers
            mountPath: /var/log/containers
          - name: varlogpods
            mountPath: /var/log/pods
          - name: varlibdockercontainers
            mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          - name: my-pv
            mountPath: /my/pv/path
        volumes:
        - name: varlogcontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/containers
        - name: varlogpods
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/pods
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: my-pv
          hostPath:
            path: /my/pv/path
```

where I used my-pv as your PV mount name and /my/pv/path as a mount path. You would need to customize those.

Also depending the format of you logs, you might want to look into [parsers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html#_parsers).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the filebeat daemonset to achieve this which can be downloaded from:
`curl -L -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/7.14/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml`

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
     providers:
       - type: kubernetes
         node: ${NODE_NAME}
         hints.enabled: true
         hints.default_config:
           type: container
           paths:
             - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
```

Filebeat daemonset reads from stderr and you can follow either of the two approaches:

1. You can create the dockerfile in such a way that, it writes the logs to the stderr, something similar to what Nginx folks have done:

```
# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Repo Info (https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L21-L23)

2)Use a streaming sidecar, as described in Kubernetes docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container.

Sample Dockerfile

```
FROM  node:13.3.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /app/path/jsonfile.json
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Sample filebeat daemonset

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    # filebeat.inputs:
    # - type: container
    #   paths:
    #     - /var/log/containers/*.log
    #   json.keys_under_root: true
    #   json.add_error_key: true
    #   json.message_key: message
    #   processors:
    #     - add_kubernetes_metadata:
    #         host: ${NODE_NAME}
    #         matchers:
    #         - logs_path:
    #             logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
            
    # To enable hints based autodiscover, remove `filebeat.inputs` configuration and uncomment this:
    filebeat.autodiscover:
     providers:
       - type: kubernetes
         node: ${NODE_NAME}
         hints.enabled: true
         hints.default_config:
           type: container
           paths:
             - /var/log/containers/*${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log

    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
      - add_host_metadata:
      # - add_kubernetes_metadata:

    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}

    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
        - name: filebeat
          image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.13.3
          args: ["-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml", "-e"]
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: "elasticsearch:9200"
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: "9200"
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
              value: "elastic"
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
              value: "password"
            - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
              value:
            - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
              value:
            - name: NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            # If using Red Hat OpenShift uncomment this:
            #privileged: true
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
              readOnly: true
              subPath: filebeat.yml
            - name: data
              mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 0640
            name: filebeat-config
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
        - name: data
          hostPath:
            # When filebeat runs as non-root user, this directory needs to be writable by group (g+w).
            path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: filebeat
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
    resources:
      - namespaces
      - pods
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - watch
      - list
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - replicasets
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
```

Elasticsearch discuss forum for similar issue: (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kubernetes-autodiscovery-pod-with-multiple-log-files/207405)

Comment: Didn't not work

Comment: Linking a json file to the stderr of a node js container with a autodiscover kubernetes provider just to stream a json file to Elasticsearch is way overkill.